# When to use function reference instead of function pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

When to use function reference such as

```
void (&fr)() = foo;
fr();
```

instead of function pointer such as

```
void (*fp)() = &foo;
fp();
```

Is there something function pointer can't do but function reference can?

Comment: Also, what can be said for non-function pointers and references can also be applied to function pointers and references. There could be some exceptions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you define a reference:

```
void (&fr)() = foo;
fr();
```

it gives you the ability to use `fr` almost everywhere where it would be possible to use `foo`, which is the reason why:

```
fr();
(*fr)();
```

works exactly the same way as using the `foo` directly:

```
foo();
(*foo)();
```

**One more Difference is dereferencing a function reference doesn't result in an error where function pointer does not require dereferencing.**

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question asked. Had `fr` been declared as `void (*fr)() = &foo`, it would still be equally possibly to write `fr()`. Both can be written with or without explicit dereferences. Thus you answered a question about what the differences between function references and function pointers are, by pointing out ways they're the same...